# How to Connect Gremlin with GraphDB Ontotext

Tags: api, gremlin, graphdb

I am trying to connect gremlin to GraphDB ontotext as per [these](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/6.6/free/blueprints-rdf-support.html) steps. I am stuck at step 4 which is :

"4. Put the file graphdb-blueprints-rdf-1.0.jar in the /lib subfolder."

Where is the "graphdb-blueprints-rdf-1.0.jar" file? what is the location of it?

Answer (score 0):

Blueprints RDF Support was dropped in the newer versions of GraphDB, so that's why the jar is missing from the distribution.

Comment: Konstantin Petrov, do you know in which version exactly?

Comment: @StanislavKralin I suspect is was removed in 8.0 or 8.1. The support of the Gremlin integration was listed under experimental features and eventually dropped due to instabilities and lack of updates.